# How to simulate a lamp shade in the game engine

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I am trying to make a lamp in the blender game engine, however, I am having a lot of trouble making the light go through the lampshade in a diffuse type of illumination, how can I do this? I have tried with the modifier "cloth" and playing around with textures, but nothing seems to work.

Something like this: (http://feelgrafix.com/838711-lamp.html)

Comment: Add some translucency to your material. The cloth modifier has nothing to do with this - it is a simulation that only affects the _shape_ of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is translucency, it doesn't have anything common with cloth simulation. Most close and simple you could make - bake Translucent shader from Cycles into texture, but result actually would be good only for one point of view, so I think it would be better but much harder to write own fragment shader.